# Is there any way to detect whether the phone is locked or Unlocked in flutter?

Tags: flutter

In my case I need to detect whether the phone is locked or unlocked for some operations to do.Is it possible to do in flutter?Is there any plugin as such?

Comment: Do you want to know if the phone is unlocked even when it's using another app? Or do you just need to know when your app is in the foreground?

Comment: Yes,I want to know if the phone is unlocked even when it's using another app.It would be even more better that even if the main app is closed,I could know about whether the phone is unlocked or locked

Comment: As far as I know there's no way to know this, on Android at least, not sure about iOS. It's definitely something platform-dependent

Comment: I have found a solution which sounds quite good for my problem.You can use the screen_state plugin to achieve the above purpose.Finally I could solve my problem.ufffffff........

Comment: Interesting. I checked out the plugin. Apparently you can get notified of this in Android, I didn't know. Thanks for responding :)
The plugin doesn't seem to support iOS, though, at least according to the readme in the git repo